# Issue while trying to center Angular2-modal

Tags: angular

I am trying to center the angular2-modal

plunker:

```
"http://plnkr.co/edit/ZeRajGkGwyvKRIZkG4XQ?p=preview"
```

Click here to see the modal is top-left aligned, I am looking to seeing it centered:

```
"http://run.plnkr.co/Z5IUNqtFHzhyy5K4/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Centering can be achieved by a small css change.  Adding:

```
.modal-centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

will center the modal.